# Configure wiremock locally with different host name than localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, wiremock

I want to configure wiremock locally but with different hostname that localhost. Is this possible?

Comment: are you running wiremock standalone? which hostname do you mean?

Comment: The answer will inevitably be "yes" or "it depends". So, can you describe what it is you're having issues with in your configuration?